# Conditional Mutual information in R ; infotheo vs praznik packages

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, information-theory, mutual-information

I want to calculate conditional Mutual information in R. As far as I understood, the conditional mutual information takes 3 random variables say X,Y,Z where I(X;Y|Z) means conditional mutual information between X and Y given Z.

In "*infotheo*" package in R, there is built-in function -> **condinformation(X, Y, S=NULL, method="emp")**.
Here the condtioning variable,S can take more than one dimensions. It means it can be conditioned with more than one variable.

On the other hand, the "*praznik*" package of R also contains a built-in function -> **cmiScores(X, Y, Z, threads = 0)**. Here Z doesnt take more than one dimension.

I am confused a bit that is it possible to give more than condition in determining conditional Mutual Information. For example, if we have a vector X, vector Y and a dataframe Z of 2 or more vectors. Is it possible to calculate conditional mutual Information between X and Y given Z.